# Disable default subtitle track with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm creating an MKV container with 4 different files:

- video.mp4
- audio_en.mp4
- audio_es.mp4
- subtitles.ass

For that I'm using the following `ffmpeg` script:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio_es.mp4 -i audio_en.mp4 -i subtitles.ass \
-map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a -map 3:s \
-metadata:s:a:0 language=spa \
-metadata:s:a:1 language=eng \
-metadata:s:s:0 language=spa -disposition:s:0 -default \
-default -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:a copy -c:s copy result.mkv
```

The `result.mkv` looks awesome, everything works as expected except for one thing: subtitles are still set as the default track, so players like VLC shows them automatically. I've already tried plenty of different ways to avoid that to happen with the `disposition` flag but I cannot make it work.

How should I modify the script so that the MKV does not have the subtitles track marked as `default`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Matroska (`.mkv`) output use the [`-default_mode`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-8) option:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio_es.mp4 -i audio_en.mp4 -i subtitles.ass \
-map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a -map 3:s \
-metadata:s:a:0 language=spa \
-metadata:s:a:1 language=eng \
-metadata:s:s:0 language=spa \
-default_mode infer_no_subs \
-c copy result.mkv
```

This option requires FFmpeg 4.3 or later, or use a build from the current git master branch.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked as expected! I have been trying to find the solution for over an hour and didn't even come across that `-default_mode` option. Thanks again!

Comment: @anonymous It's relatively new and I didn't know about it either (haven't been paying much attention to development anymore).

Comment: It's odd that `-default_mode infer_no_subs` is required for this behavior. According to ffmpeg docs `The default mode is ‘passthrough’`, and `passthrough` does not set any default dispositions. I tried `-default_mode passthrough` and it also does not set disposition. Leads me to believe the actual default in ffmpeg is `infer`

Answer (score 2):

When you don't want to update to FFmpeg 4.3 this option for deposit works for me:

```
-disposition:s:0 0
```

This option overrides the disposition copied from the input stream and delete it by setting it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the file from different parts, just skip

```
-disposition:s:0 -default
```

from your script, since with that you explicitly mark that track to be default.